# Julia macro for generating boolean functions

Tags: macros, julia, metaprogramming

I have a program that often has the boolean algorithm pattern of: (f(a) && g(b)) || (f(b) && g(a)).

For example,

```
if ((isA(event[1]) && isTens(event[3])) || (isA(event[3]) && isTens(event[1])))
     cnt += 1
end
```

How can I use a macro, `@pmacro`, to do the same, so to be called as such:

```
if (@pmacro(isA(), isTens(), event[1], event[3]))
     cnt += 1
end
```

So far, I tried something like this

```
function isCombination(f, g, e1, e2)
    if (f(e1) && g(e2)) || (f(e2) && g(e1))
        true
    else
        false
    end
end
```

And,

```
julia> isCombination(BJcore.isA, BJcore.isTens, event[1], event[3])
```

Works but, should I use meta-programming here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a macro for that. Since Julia supports higher order programming, you can define a function - I'll call it `predicate` here - that accepts the functions `f` and `g` as arguments and performs the required check.

```
julia> predicate(f, g, a, b) = (f(a) && g(b) || f(b) && g(a))
predicate (generic function with 1 method)

julia> predicate(iseven, isodd, 4, 3)
true

julia> predicate(iseven, isodd, 3, 3)
false

julia> predicate(iseven, isodd, 3, 4)
true
```

---

*Edit*: The edit to the question happened while I was writing the answer, but you've hit upon the solution. `isCombination` and `predicate` are pretty much the same function.

As for metaprogramming: when there's a non-metaprogramming solution to a problem, the answer to "should I use metaprogramming" is almost always no. Metaprogramming is a powerful tool, but can make your code harder to read and maintain unless applied judiciously and with care.